# Can't get X-Facebook-Locale header

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I would like to know how to get `X-Facebook-Locale` header when displaying an app in an appropriated language.

I'm not sure if my app is crawled by facebook so I put `scraped=true` when publishing an action and at tag `og:description` I put `content="I displayed $_SERVER here"` to know what elements are in header. I also added tag `og:locale:alternalte` to `en_us` and `fr_fr`. About `og:locale` I have to know the content of `X-facebook-Locale` to use apropriated language but I can't view this header anywhere. Can someone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried to get the contents of this HTTP header? And you don’t necessarily _have_ to look for this header – Facebook will also add a URL parameter `fb_locale` as an alternative.

Comment: to get HTTP header contents I used print_r php function on $_SERVER.

Answer (score 2):

after hours trying to make the locale feature work and getting the same problem as you, I change my code to verify the locale using the HEADER **X-facebook-Locale**.

I don't know the exactly programing language that you are using but in PHP, I check the Header content with this code:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['X-Facebook-Locale']))
{
    $locale = strtolower($header['X-Facebook-Locale']);
}
```

Requesting only the HEADER value works for me.

Good luck.

Best Regards

Gabriel Pires

Comment: `USER-AGENT: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) 
HOST: www.tymek.cz 
ACCEPT: */* 
ACCEPT-ENCODING: deflate, gzip 
RANGE: bytes=0-524287 
CONNECTION: close` 
What now? Does not work in debuger. How to receive `X-Facebook-Locale`?